# Will crontab hour range a-b run after b too?

Tags: cron

Say I have a crontab which runs every `20` minutes and I have a hour range which can vary so lets say `a-b`, which in one example could look like

```
*/20 5-23 * * * /usr/bin/cool_program
```

My question is, will the cron run at 23:00, 23:20, 23:40 and 00:00 too?

Comment: Hey @nikola I believe you have selected the wrong answer as the solution. The other 2 answers differ from what @gks says. gks says the cron will stop running at `23` but the correct answer is that it will stop running at `23:40` with your crontab.

Comment: @brandonbanks thanks for pointing it out, I must have missed the additional answers to this question.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[GK27's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352399/will-crontab-hour-range-a-b-run-after-b-too/16352534#16352534) does not fully answer the question, so let me clarify:

`cron` will run jobs when the time matches the expression provided. Your expression tells it to run when the minute is divisible by 20 (`*/20`) and your hour range tells it to run when the hour is within the specified range inclusively (`5-23`). The remaining three `*` tell it to match any day, month, and any day of the week.

Therefore the first job will run at 05:00 because the hour, `05`, is in the range 5 to 23 and the minute, `00`, is divisible by 20. The last job will run at 23:40 because the hour, `23`, is in the range 5 to 23 and the minute, `40`, is divisible by 20. It will not run at 00:00 because the hour, `00`, is not in the range 5 to 23.

Comment: Great explanation! This clarifies the logic of the scripts. So if I want 00:00, I would need one more line: `0 00 * * *`. Right?

Comment: @Nakamura you should be able to just do `0 0 * * *` That will run the first minute of the first hour everyday.

Answer (score 8):

@Alex's answer is correct, however it took me a while to find a source.

The answer is in `man crontab.5` (or also `info crontab`) on [Debian](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/cron/crontab.5.en.html), [Mac OS X](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?crontab(5)), [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?crontab(5)) (and other [Posix](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/crontab) systems):

> Ranges of numbers are allowed.  Ranges are two numbers separated with
>   a hyphen.  The specified range is inclusive.  For example,  8-11  for 
>   an ``hours'' entry specifies execution at hours 8, 9, 10 and 11.

For my application I wanted a script to run every 5 minutes during business hours (9am - 5pm) and another to run every 5 minutes outside of that. Unfortunately the ranges can't wrap across midnight, so you need to specify 3 ranges (morning, business hours, evening)

```
*/5 0-8,17-23   * * *   outside-hours.sh
*/5 9-16   * * *   business-hours.sh
```

This should run

```
outside-hours.sh  first at 00:00 and finally at 08:55
business-hours.sh first at 09:00 and finally at 16:55
outside-hours.sh  first at 17:00 and finally at 23:55
```

Comment: You said the other answers are correct but it appears that the selected answer does not agree with your answer. They said it should stop running at 23:00, "* 5-23 – 5.20 am,5.40 am,6 am,....23 pm". but `*/5 0-8 * * *` would stop running at 08:55.

Comment: @brandonbanks Yes on re-reading, the accepted answer is not correct. Thanks I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry I didn’t notice this before, I selected the correct answer now. I also updated this one for the clear example.

Answer (score 5):

It will execute when `minute` is divisible by 20 and when hour is in `5-23` inclusive:

```
* 20 – every 20 minutes from 0 to 59
* 5-23 – 5 to 23 inclusive
* * – Every day
* * – Every month
* * - EvryDay of the Week
```

The first occurrence is 5:00 and the last 23:40

[crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#*/20_5-23_*_*_*)

[Documentation for Reference](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/)

Comment: So is this actually incorrect? What I'm seeing is that the hour range is inclusive. This would mean that the cron would stop running at `23:40`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in `man 5 crontab`. Range is allowed.

```
      The time and date fields are:

              field          allowed values
              -----          --------------
              minute         0-59
              hour           0-23
              day of month   1-31
              month          1-12 (or names, see below)
              day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sunday, or use names)

       A field may contain an asterisk (*), which always stands for "first-last".

       Ranges of numbers are allowed.  Ranges are two numbers separated with a hyphen.  The specified range is inclusive.  
       
       
       For example, 8-11 for an 'hours' entry specifies execution at hours 8, 9, 10, and 11. The first number must be less than or equal to the second one.
```