# Scheduled Cron is running beyond the stated time in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks

I am scheduling a cron operation like this

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */5 11-15 * * SUN-THU", zone = "Asia/Kolkata")
public void cronner() throws ParseException {
        System.out.println("cron is running");
}
```

So, this means, run the job every 5 minutes from 11 am to 3 pm from Sunday to Thursday. 
This is working great but the problem is, it is still running after 3 pm.
I am getting the log `cron is running` even after 3 pm. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this problem is not clock/timezone related?

Comment: I am specifying a time zone (updated the question) but the job is running even after it is 3pm in Kolkata.

Comment: I suggest you to remove the zone property and verify that the problem will not continue. If your local is not equal to that time zone then it should stop after 3pm.

Comment: Daylight saving time between your zone and Asia/Kolkata which is not observing DST? Are you sure it's 3pm in Asia/Kolkata e.g. not running a very old JDK with outdated tz information?

Comment: @theanilpaudel Is it running only for a couple of additional hours or is it running all the way until 11am?

Comment: it goes till 4 pm

Answer (score 1):

I guess this works as designed. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352399/will-crontab-hour-range-a-b-run-after-b-too) for example.

You specify it should run every 5 minutes for every hour that starts with 11, 12, 13, 14 or 15. So 15:55 is a perfectly fine starting time. You should not see a start after 16:00.