# crontab week of the day not working - it send everyday

Tags: cron

I use crontab for send email in every first, third Monday.

I tried `MON` and `1` both, but it worked everyday.

Here's my crontab - I tried both, but both send everyday

```
0 09 1-7,15-21 * MON
0 09 1-7,15-21 * 1
```

I think there's no problem with the syntax. What can I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What tool are you using with this CRON expression?  The format/rules are not the same everywhere.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oh I use crontab in ubuntu 16.04. Is there any version difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct, documented behavior.  From `man 5 crontab` on Ubuntu 16.04 (emphasis mine):

> Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields — day of month, and  day
>   of  week.  **If both fields are restricted (i.e., aren't *), the command will be run when either
>   field matches the current time.**  For example,
>   `30 4 1,15 * 5` would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on  the  1st  and  15th  of  each
>    month, **plus** every Friday. One can, however, achieve the desired result by adding a test to the
>   command (see the last example in EXAMPLE CRON FILE below).

Later in the man page they give an example that does just the sort of thing you want:

```
   # Run on every second Saturday of the month
   0 4 8-14 * *    test $(date +\%u) -eq 6 && echo "2nd Saturday"
```

Comment: Oh the answer is almost same. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, what's `test` for in your example crontab?

Comment: `man test`.  It is the command that actually does the test for equality (because of being given the `-eq` option).  Your example, with the word `test` left out, won't work.

Answer (score 1):

From what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352399/will-crontab-hour-range-a-b-run-after-b-too), ranges can't wrap around midnight.  You might try creating separate CRON jobs for each each possible Monday day, e.g.

```
0 09 1 * MON
0 09 2 * MON
...
0 09 7 * MON
0 09 15 * MON
0 09 16 * MON
...
0 09 21 * MON
```

Comment: I use range in the day - is it matter that ranges can't wrap around midnight?

Comment: I don't know...if my answer works, then apparently yes.  If not, I'm happy to delete this.  It could also be that it doesn't like multiple ranges.

Comment: Oh you mean it applied multiple range both... day + week of the day. I'll figure out more. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found it in `man 5 crontab`

> Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields — day of month, and day of week. If both fields are restricted (i.e., aren't *), the command will be run when either field matches the current time. For example, ``30 4 1,15 * 5'' would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus every Friday. One can, however, achieve the desired result by adding a test to the command (see the last example in EXAMPLE CRON FILE below).

So it means the day (1-7,15-21) and week of the day (MON) both applied.

When want to specify both day and week of the day, try using `date`

```
0 09 1-7,15-21 * $(date +\%Wu) -eq 1 && my_job
```